# Can Maddening Darkness be cast on an object to move with it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, targeting

This is the text from Maddening Darkness:

> Magical darkness spreads from a point you choose within range to fill
>   a 60—foot—radius sphere until the spell ends. The darkness spreads
>   around corners. A creature with darkvision can’t see through this
>   darkness. Nonmagical light, as well as light created by spells of 8th
>   level or lower, can't illuminate the area. Shrieks, gibbering, and mad
>   laughter can be heard within the sphere. Whenever a creature starts
>   its turn in the sphere, it must make a Wisdom saving throw, taking 8d8
>   psychic damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a
>   successful one.

This is the text from Darkness:

> Magical darkness spreads from a point you choose within range to f
>   ill a 15-foot radius sphere for the duration. The darkness spreads
>   around corners. A creature with darkvision can’t see through this
>   darkness, and nonmagical light can’t illuminate it.
>
> If the point you choose is on an object you are holding or one that
>   isn’t being worn or carried, the darkness emanates from the object and
>   moves with it. Completely covering the source of the darkness with an
>   opaque object, such as a bowl or a helm, blocks the darkness.
>
> If any of this spell’s area overlaps with an area of light created by
>   a spell of 2nd level or lower, the spell that created the light is
>   dispelled.

Maddening Darkness doesn't specify that you can cast the spell on an object, but it uses the same wordage *"from a point you choose within range"*. Can you interpret this to mean that Maddening Darkness can also be cast on an object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No, Maddening Darkness has a fixed position

This is a case of Specific vs General

The general rule is that when you cast a spell, its area of effect is fixed. Once you select its point of origin, it stays there.

> Typically, a point of origin is a point in space, but some spells have an area whose origin is a creature or an object.

This clearly indicates that, unless a spell explicitly says otherwise, a "point you choose within range" is a point in space. This is seen in spells like Fog Cloud, Create Bonfire, etc.

Some spells, such as Darkness, Anti-magic zone, Aura of Life, etc. invoke the exception to make the point of origin an object or creature that can move, taking the spell with it. Every such spell explicitly states what the target can be and that the spell "moves with [you/it]."

If Maddening Darkness could be relocated by aiming it at an object, and then moving that object, the spell would explicitly say so. Without a specific override, Maddening Darkness is subject to the general rule that your target is a 'point in space.'